# Impossible to add influxdb datasource grafana - Network error : Undefined (undefined)

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm trying to add an influxdb datasource on grafana but there are some issues.

First I took a sample database on influxdb's website:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/noaa.water-database/NOAA_data.txt

Then I've completed the grafana form like that: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWB8R.png)

And finally I'm facing this Network Error.
Here's what I see in the network tool: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onHmW.png)

I'm a beginner with grafana so I guess i'm doing something wrong. Sure a little help would be great! Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

You didn't configure InfluxDB datasource correctly. Mentioned URL http://s3.amazonaws.com/noaa.water-database/NOAA_data.txt is a text file that contains the data in line protocol format, which you need to import into your InfluxDB server first. Then use used InfluxDB server address in your Grafana datasource configuration.

There is a [InfluxDB documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.6/query_language/data_download/#download-and-write-the-data-to-influxdb), which will help you with the import.